# Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: c#, iis-7, web-config, telerik

I am trying to deploy a C# .NET 4.5 application on IIS7 that uses Telerik UI. For some reason I am getting the following error when I navigate to my login page

```
GET http://localhost/dev/3pt_upgrade/portal/Automation_Framework/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have tried everything on [The Telerik Web Resources Troubleshooting guide](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-web-resources-troubleshooting.html)

In my Web.config I have

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        ...
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>    
        <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.3.1114.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Any insight on the matter would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to see what error was thrown inside the .axd call. In my case was a bad path to telerik.common.css file.